# How to set Org mode export ODT defaults for US standards

Tags: org-mode, org-export, odt

I am using Xubuntu Linux and I like to use Emacs Org mode for all my writing, and then export to Libreoffice. At first the default `style.xml` file set the page style  to A4 and used centimeters instead of inches. This changed after I logged into a root account and opened Libreoffice, setting my defaults to en-US, etc. I also made a go at editing the `style.xml` file to replace `cm` measurements with `in` measurements. I really had no clue what I was doing. Things seem to be working well now, but if I need to create a new system installation, I fear that I will lose these settings. Is there an easier way to make these adjustments. i.e. change everything from the start to US norms as opposed to EU defaults? Setting `#+LANGUAGE: en-US` had no effect in my org file; I understand this is primarily for html files.

Comment: have you tried setting the export styles file to something other than the default? i suspect if you use `#+ODT_STYLES_FILE:` to point to your current open office default template, or to a new one of your choosing, it will pick up your local settings. see https://orgmode.org/manual/Applying-custom-styles.html for more. mostly you wouldn't want to use the default template anyway, you can make much nicer looking documents by exporting using your own.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting the  below Org snippet will produce US letter-sized documents, and it will be in English/US locale. For this snippet to work, you need to install the [The enhanced ODT exporter](https://kjambunathan.gitlab.io/org-mode-ox-odt/Getting-Started-with-ODT-export.html#Installation) with `M-x package-install`.

```
#+LANGUAGE: en_US

#+odt_extra_automatic_styles: <style:page-layout style:name="DefaultPageLayout"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                    style:page-usage="mirrored">
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:   <style:page-layout-properties fo:margin-bottom="2cm"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                           fo:margin-left="2cm"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                           fo:margin-right="2cm"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                           fo:margin-top="2cm"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                           fo:page-height="27.94cm"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                           fo:page-width="21.59cm"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                           style:footnote-max-height="0cm"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                           style:layout-grid-base-height="0.706cm"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                           style:layout-grid-color="#c0c0c0"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                           style:layout-grid-display="false"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                           style:layout-grid-lines="20"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                           style:layout-grid-mode="none"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                           style:layout-grid-print="false"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                           style:layout-grid-ruby-below="false"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                           style:layout-grid-ruby-height="0.353cm"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                           style:num-format="1"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                           style:print-orientation="portrait"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                           style:writing-mode="lr-tb">
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:     <style:footnote-sep style:adjustment="left"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                   style:color="#000000"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                   style:distance-after-sep="0.101cm"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                   style:distance-before-sep="0.101cm"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                   style:line-style="solid"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                   style:rel-width="25%"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                   style:width="0.018cm" />
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:   </style:page-layout-properties>
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:   <style:header-style />
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:   <style:footer-style>
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:     <style:header-footer-properties fo:background-color="transparent"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                                     fo:margin-left="0cm"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                                     fo:margin-right="0cm"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                                     fo:margin-top="0.499cm"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                                     fo:min-height="0.6cm"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                                     style:dynamic-spacing="false" />
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:   </style:footer-style>
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles: </style:page-layout>

#+odt_extra_automatic_styles: <style:style style:name="DefaultFooter"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:              style:parent-style-name="Footer"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:              style:family="paragraph">
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:   <style:paragraph-properties fo:text-align="center"
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles:                               style:justify-single-word="false" />
#+odt_extra_automatic_styles: </style:style>


#+odt_master_styles: <style:master-page style:name="Standard"
#+odt_master_styles:                    style:page-layout-name="DefaultPageLayout">
#+odt_master_styles:   <style:footer>
#+odt_master_styles:     <text:p text:style-name="DefaultFooter">
#+odt_master_styles:       <text:page-number text:select-page="current"/>
#+odt_master_styles:     </text:p>
#+odt_master_styles:   </style:footer>
#+odt_master_styles: </style:master-page>

Some text
```

The style configuration will look a bit overwhelming, at first.  You can learn about it in

1. [Create a stylesheet for your OpenDocument files, and inline the XML definitions right in your Org file–Think HTML_HEAD, or HTML_HEAD_EXTRA but for ODT / DOCX files](https://emacsnotes.wordpress.com/2020/06/21/create-a-stylesheet-for-your-opendocument-files-and-inline-the-xml-definitions-right-in-your-org-file-think-html_head-or-html_head_extra-but-for-odt-docx-files/)
2. [Applying custom styles through keywords](https://kjambunathan.gitlab.io/org-mode-ox-odt/Applying-custom-styles.html#Applying-custom-styles-through-keywords)
   .

Btw, the units used in `styles.xml` doesn't matter--it can either be in `in`s or `cm`s.  What you need to do is to configure your LibreOffice UI to display the measurements in `in`s instead of `cm`s.  See [Selecting Measurement Units](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/shared/guide/measurement_units.html) .